# Injetivity of a function

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Let f: U $\rightarrow R^{m}$ differentiable in $U \in R^m$. If $|f(x)|$ is constant in $U$, then for all $x \in U$ $, f'(x)$ is not injective. 
Hint: Derive the function $||f(x)||^{2}$. And verify that the image of $f'(x)$ can not contain the vector $f(x)$, i.e, $f'(x).v \neq f(x)$ for all $v \in R^m$.

I'm trying to solve as follows.

Let $\phi : U \rightarrow R$ defined by $\phi (x)= ||f(x)||^2 = <f(x),f(x)>  =||f(x)||.||f(x)||$.

Thus,

$\phi'(x) = 2<f'(x),f(x)> = 2||f(x)||'.||f(x)|| = 0$

$\phi'(x).v = 2<f'(x).v,f(x)> = 0$ for all $v \in R^m$.

Therefore $f'(x).v$ is ortogonal to $f(x)$. Then $f'(x).v \neq f(x)$ for all $v \in R^m$.

My solution is correct? Would have another way to solve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention also that for linear transformation of the finite dimensional space the notions 'to be injective' and 'to be surjective' are equivalent due to existence of determinant.